# There is a line in the middle of my stroke. How do I fix that?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

I am trying to make a circle with dash but there's a black line that wont go away.

How do I fix this? I have looked through the appearances tab. I have also tried deleting that object then redoing it but, nothing has worked. It is one single image that has three strokes on it. It might just be a glitch in my program.

> [image: The image with the appearance panel.]

Comment: Simply looks as though you have a stoke on top of the Appearance stack.

Comment: can you show us what your appearance pane looks like? Also the layers pane- is this a group or a single object?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have multiple strokes applied to your shape, you want to remove the extra ones.

Since you don't see it in the appearance panel, it is likely applied to the layer.

Select the layer from the *Layers panel* (<kbd>F7</kbd>) and then go to the *Appearance panel* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>), you will probably find a 1pt solid black stroke there, just go ahead and remove it.

If you just select the item, you will also see an indication on the top of the appearance panel that there are settings applied to the layer.