# Unwanted outline in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, illustrator-effects, outline

None of the objects I'm working with have a stroke on them, however all of them display an outline that shows up through other objects in illustrator. It looks as though I'm in preview mode with colors turned on? I can't figure out how to turn this setting off, help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is a line in the middle of my stroke. How do I fix that?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120855/63979)

Answer (score 8):

You have a stroke applied to the layer: the dot at the right of the layer (*target icon*) is filled, this means there are some attributes applied to the whole layer:

[image: layers]

[image]

Read more about the target icon at [Adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/appearance-attributes.html#targeting_items_for_appearance_attributes)

---

Click the *target icon* at the right of the layer name to select the layer items and check at the Appearance Panel there is no any stroke applied to it

[image]